# How to find the number of occurrences of a letter in only the first sentence of a string?

Tags: c#, string, char

I want to find number of letter "a" in only first sentence. The code below finds "a" in all sentences, but I want in only first sentence.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text;  int k = 0;
    text = "bla bla bla. something second. maybe last sentence.";

    foreach (char a in text)
    {
        char b = 'a';
        if (b == a)
        {
            k += 1;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("number of a in first sentence is " + k);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Please trace through your code until you can come up with a more specific question.

Comment: You must first determine the first sentence. Isolate that. Then finding the first 'a' is trivial. Unfortunately, accurately identifying a sentence may indeed be non-trivial.

Comment: How do you define a sentence?  A period might occur in all sorts of places... like 1.5 or "She said, "Woah."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perhaps more verbose than what you were looking for, but hopefully it'll breed understanding as you read through it.

```
public static void Main()
    {
        //Make an array of the possible sentence enders. Doing this pattern lets us easily update
        // the code later if it becomes necessary, or allows us easily to move this to an input
        // parameter
        string[] SentenceEnders = new string[] {"$", @"\.", @"\?", @"\!" /* Add Any Others */};
        string WhatToFind = "a"; //What are we looking for? Regular Expressions Will Work Too!!!
        string SentenceToCheck = "This, but not to exclude any others, is a sample."; //First example
        string MultipleSentencesToCheck = @"
        Is this a sentence
        that breaks up
        among multiple lines?
        Yes!
        It also has
        more than one
        sentence.
        "; //Second Example

        //This will split the input on all the enders put together(by way of joining them in [] inside a regular
        // expression.
        string[] SplitSentences = Regex.Split(SentenceToCheck, "[" + String.Join("", SentenceEnders) + "]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        //SplitSentences is an array, with sentences on each index. The first index is the first sentence
        string FirstSentence = SplitSentences[0];

        //Now, split that single sentence on our matching pattern for what we should be counting
        string[] SubSplitSentence = Regex.Split(FirstSentence, WhatToFind, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        //Now that it's split, it's split a number of times that matches how many matches we found, plus one
        // (The "Left over" is the +1
        int HowMany = SubSplitSentence.Length - 1;

        System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("We found, in the first sentence, {0} '{1}'.", HowMany, WhatToFind));

        //Do all this again for the second example. Note that ideally, this would be in a separate function
        // and you wouldn't be writing code twice, but I wanted you to see it without all the comments so you can
        // compare and contrast

        SplitSentences = Regex.Split(MultipleSentencesToCheck, "[" + String.Join("", SentenceEnders) + "]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        SubSplitSentence = Regex.Split(SplitSentences[0], WhatToFind, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        HowMany = SubSplitSentence.Length - 1;

        System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("We found, in the second sentence, {0} '{1}'.", HowMany, WhatToFind));
    }
```

Here is the output:

```
We found, in the first sentence, 3 'a'.
We found, in the second sentence, 4 'a'.
```

Comment: Sure hope your production code isn't written like that.  You are wasting hard drive space with all that.  :)

Comment: Wasting hard drive space? Because of a few extra characters? You should look up the concept of readable code vs shorter code - most agree that readable / supportable is much better.

Comment: I was being sarcastic about the hard drive space.  However - there is a fine line between unreadable code, readable code, and too much code.  Remember - the more code you write to solve the same problem increases the potential for bugs.  The LINQ based solution given above (single line) is very readable as well as short and sweet.  The only draw back to the the link solution would be if you had to debug it and inspect the loops - but in this case that seems like overkill.

Comment: Sorry - I totally missed the sarcasm. =) And though there are more "potential lines" for bugs, I also find that there are less bugs overall because the workings are more intuitive and easy to follow. That said, I have no problem with the LINQ examples either but people new to programming might not be able to really understand what's going on without this kind of breakout.

Answer (score 9):

This will split the string into an array seperated by '.', then counts the number of 'a' char's in the first element of the array (the first sentence).

```
var count = Text.Split(new[] { '.', '!', '?', })[0].Count(c => c == 'a');
```

This example assumes a sentence is separated by a **.**, **?** or **!**. If you have a decimal number in your string (e.g. 123.456), that will count as a sentence break. Breaking up a string into accurate sentences is a fairly complex exercise.

Comment: I would include '!' and '?' as the split arguments but otherwise it's the most elegant way of doing this.

Comment: Nice answer, include a case where text entered has no ".", for my upvote.

Comment: Nice answer, shorter and easier than mine. +1 for you!! :)

Comment: @EmmanuelN, I'm not sure what it should do then. Count the entire String as one sentence, or as no sentence at all? This was a quick and dirty example with none of the required defensive coding I'd normally do ;)

Comment: @DaveShaw, I don't care as long as "index out of range error" is taken care

Comment: @EmmanuelN: This is the role of the OP to make sure before trying this line to check if there is a splitting character in is sentence. Plus, he tagged with [homework], let him find failure cases alone.

Comment: Calling String.Split on an empty String will return an array with an empty string at index 0. Calling String.Split on a string that doesn't match any of the split characters will return the whole String at index 0 in the array. Just tested with "abc" and "" as Text.

Comment: @Otiel, actually it was tagged by a SO member as 'homework'. :)

Comment: @DaveShaw: Right :) I found it curious that a new user would tag his question as [homework], not to be malicious.

Comment: yeah, it was homeworks one part. i shall tag similar questions as homework at another time :). I'm new there, and in programming too.

Comment: Sure wish Stackoverflow was around when I was in college to do my homework for me too.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define "sentence", but if we assume it's always terminated by a period (`.`), just add this inside the loop:

```
if (a == '.') {
    break;
}
```

Expand from this to support other sentence delimiters.

Comment: Yeah, you do need to define sentence. Beware of sentences like "One day, Mr. Barnes went to the store."

Comment: i thought so many about it and knew it was very easy. thanks man, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Simply "break" the `foreach(...)` loop when you encounter a "." (period)

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you define a sentence as being ended with a '.''

Use String.IndexOf() to find the position of the first '.'. After that, searchin a SubString instead of the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

1. find the place of the '.' in the text ( you can use split )
2. count the 'a' in the text from the place 0 to instance of the '.'

Answer (score 0):

```
       string SentenceToCheck = "Hi, I can wonder this situation where I can do best";

      //Here I am giving several way to find this
        //Using Regular Experession

        int HowMany = Regex.Split(SentenceToCheck, "a", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Length - 1;
        int i = Regex.Matches(SentenceToCheck, "a").Count;
        // Simple way

        int Count = SentenceToCheck.Length - SentenceToCheck.Replace("a", "").Length;

        //Linq

        var _lamdaCount = SentenceToCheck.ToCharArray().Where(t => t.ToString() != string.Empty)
            .Select(t => t.ToString().ToUpper().Equals("A")).Count();

       var _linqAIEnumareable = from _char in SentenceToCheck.ToCharArray()
                                 where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(_char.ToString())
                                 && _char.ToString().ToUpper().Equals("A")
                                 select _char;

        int a =linqAIEnumareable.Count;

        var _linqCount = from g in SentenceToCheck.ToCharArray()
                         where g.ToString().Equals("a")
                         select g;
        int a = _linqCount.Count();
```